# why does something disappear in the aligned environment?

Tags: equations, align

I noticed a strange behaviour with the aligned environment:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:direct_limit}
\begin{aligned}
[x] + [y] & := [\eta_{ik}(x) + \eta_{jk}(y)],\\
[x] \cdot r & := [x \cdot r].
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
```

If I compile this, the first "[x]" in the equation is missing. 
Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `[x]` is misinterpreted as the optional argument for `aligned`. You can use a `\relax`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:direct_limit}
\begin{aligned}\relax
[x] + [y] & := [\eta_{ik}(x) + \eta_{jk}(y)],\\ [x] \cdot r & := [x \cdot r].
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `:=` you could use `\coloneqq` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:direct_limit}
\begin{aligned}\relax
[x] + [y] & \coloneqq [\eta_{ik}(x) + \eta_{jk}(y)],\\ 
[x] \cdot r & \coloneqq [x \cdot r].
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use an empty `{}` to prevent `[x]` from getting added as optional argument of `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:direct_limit}
\begin{aligned}
{}[x] + [y] & := [\eta_{ik}(x) + \eta_{jk}(y)],\\
[x] \cdot r & := [x \cdot r].
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to use `mathtools` package to fix the problem in `\\` command and `amsmath`'s some environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:direct_limit}
\begin{aligned}
[x] + [y] & := [\eta_{ik}(x) + \eta_{jk}(y)],\\
[x] \cdot r & := [x \cdot r].
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```